# Trying to search for a specific word in a 2-d array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to build a program that will search for anything the user inputs in a 2d array that I have built with a bunch of letters and numbers. The program needs to find the word, say the location of the word in index number form and somehow a way of telling how many times the word has appeared. I have found ways off doing this however they require me to use other libraries other than include  and 
include  which I am not allowed to. I know that this is a very specific question but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. There are a total of 117 characters and letters in the char meaningless if that helps at all.
`

```
void wordSearch()

{ 

int i;
char search[30];
char meaningless[5][30]=
printf("\"
printf("Please enter the word you would like to search for in the above text\n");
scanf("%s", &search);
for(i=0, i<117, i++)
    {
    } 
 }
```

`

Comment: `scanf("%s", &search);` is wrong, remove the `'&'` -- `search` is already a pointer. [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)Get the length of `search` after the user enters it and then use `strncmp()` remembering to stop the search `length` before the end of each element.

Answer (score 1):

You wordsearch is fairly straight forward. You want to write a useful function that can be reused to search for any word that is a substring of a larger string. What that means in your case is you want to write a function that will look for `search` within each string (row) contained in `meaningless`.

To begin, do NOT add a dangling `'\n'` to the last row in `meaningless` just to gain an extra newline when `meaningless` is output. Handle your output spacing with your output function, either adding an additional `'\n'` to your `printf` format string or simply outputting a newline with `putchar('\n');`

Let's start with your `main()` and how you will loop over each row in `meaningless`, both for outputting it and for passing each line to the `wordsearch` function. Let's start with your declaration of `meaningless`. Avoid using *Magic Numbers* in your code. If you need a constant, `#define` one, e.g.

```
#define MAXC 32     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
int main (void) {

    char search[MAXC],  /* array to hold search term */
         meaningless[][MAXC] ={ "AMENFELANGUAGEFERVZ0PIBMOU",   /* to search */
                                "ZBPOINTERSSKLM12PMNOCOT",
                                "YCPROGRAMMERWQKNULTHMD",
                                "UKUNIXFIMWXIZEQZINPUTEX",
                                "P0DSTRINGGDIWHIMERCERLS" };
    int rows = sizeof meaningless / sizeof *meaningless;        /* no. of rows */
    ...
```

The recommended way of handling a line of input is to read the input with `fgets()`. That way you consume a line of input each time and what remains in `stdin` doesn't depend on the *format-string* used. In your case, presumably you want to be able to enter multiple search terms each time your program runs. To do that you can simply loop continually, displaying your `meaningless` block of characters and prompting for input from the user.

The nice thing about `fgets()` is it will read the `'\n'` created by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> which provides a simple way to end input -- just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> without any input and check to see if the 1st character in `search` is `'\n'`. If it is, break the loop. If it isn't, then you need to trim the `'\n'` from the end of search which is easily done with `strcspn()`, e.g.

```
        /* prompt for search, read and VALIDATE input, comparse 1st char with '\n' */
        fputs ("\nenter search term: ", stdout);
        if (!fgets (search, MAXC, stdin) || *search == '\n')
            break;

        search[strcspn (search, "\n")] = 0;     /* trim trailing '\n' from search */
```

(**note:** by checking `!fgets(...)` you also handle the case where the user generates a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows)

You also want to know how many times `search` was matched. So within your continual loop, simply declare an `int` variable and initialize the value to zero (e.g. `int matches = 0;`). Adding that, your complete `main()` searching for `search` withing `meaningless` for as many terms as the user cares to search for until <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone is pressed (or a manual `EOF` generated) could be:

```
int main (void) {

    char search[MAXC],  /* array to hold search term */
         meaningless[][MAXC] ={ "AMENFELANGUAGEFERVZ0PIBMOU",   /* to search */
                                "ZBPOINTERSSKLM12PMNOCOT",
                                "YCPROGRAMMERWQKNULTHMD",
                                "UKUNIXFIMWXIZEQZINPUTEX",
                                "P0DSTRINGGDIWHIMERCERLS" };
    int rows = sizeof meaningless / sizeof *meaningless;        /* no. of rows */

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until no search term provided */
        int matches = 0;    /* no. of matches of search found */

        putchar ('\n');                         /* provide newline */
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)          /* loop over each meaningless row */
            printf ("%s\n", meaningless[i]);    /* output */

        /* prompt for search, read and VALIDATE input, comparse 1st char with '\n' */
        fputs ("\nenter search term: ", stdout);
        if (!fgets (search, MAXC, stdin) || *search == '\n')
            break;

        search[strcspn (search, "\n")] = 0;     /* trim trailing '\n' from search */

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)          /* loop over each meaningless row */
            matches += wordsearch (meaningless[i], search); /* check for matches */

        printf ("\n\"%s\" found %d times.\n", search, matches); /* output results */
    }
}
```

Your `wordsearch()` function is straight forward. You will pass the string to look through (`haystack`) and the term to find (`needle`) and then see if you can find the needle in the haystack. The approach is to declare a pointer to the first char in the haystack, and then use `strchr` to find if and where the first character of `needle` occurs in the `haystack`. If it is found, then you just check the next `needle` length worth of characters to see if they match `needle` using `strncmp()` and then advance the pointer to the next char and repeat.

The only caveat is you want to stop searching if you are less than the length of `needle` chars away from the end of `haystack` (obviously you can't match in less than `needle` no. of characters) -- and more importantly, you prevent reading beyond the end of your string invoking *Undefined Behavior*...

With that said, your `wordsearch()` could put those pieces together as follows, returning the number of times `needle` is found in `haystack`, e.g.

```
/* seach haystack for needle, return no. of times needle occurs */
int wordsearch (const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    const char *p = haystack;               /* string to search within */
    int found = 0;                          /* no. of matches found */
    size_t  hlen = strlen (haystack),       /* lenght of string to search within */
            nlen = strlen (needle);         /* length of seach string */

    /* loop while pointer more than nlen chars from end and 1st char in needle found */
    while ((size_t)(p - haystack) < (hlen - nlen) && (p = strchr (p, *needle))) {
        if (strncmp (p, needle, nlen) == 0) /* if next nlen chars match needle */
            found += 1;                     /* increment found by 1 */
        p += 1;                             /* increment point to next char */
    }

    return found;   /* return no. of needles in haystack */
}
```

Adding the required headers and a complete example could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 32     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

/* seach haystack for needle, return no. of times needle occurs */
int wordsearch (const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    const char *p = haystack;               /* string to search within */
    int found = 0;                          /* no. of matches found */
    size_t  hlen = strlen (haystack),       /* lenght of string to search within */
            nlen = strlen (needle);         /* length of seach string */

    /* loop while pointer more than nlen chars from end and 1st char in needle found */
    while ((size_t)(p - haystack) < (hlen - nlen) && (p = strchr (p, *needle))) {
        if (strncmp (p, needle, nlen) == 0) /* if next nlen chars match needle */
            found += 1;                     /* increment found by 1 */
        p += 1;                             /* increment point to next char */
    }

    return found;   /* return no. of needles in haystack */
}

int main (void) {

    char search[MAXC],  /* array to hold search term */
         meaningless[][MAXC] ={ "AMENFELANGUAGEFERVZ0PIBMOU",   /* to search */
                                "ZBPOINTERSSKLM12PMNOCOT",
                                "YCPROGRAMMERWQKNULTHMD",
                                "UKUNIXFIMWXIZEQZINPUTEX",
                                "P0DSTRINGGDIWHIMERCERLS" };
    int rows = sizeof meaningless / sizeof *meaningless;        /* no. of rows */

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until no search term provided */
        int matches = 0;    /* no. of matches of search found */

        putchar ('\n');                         /* provide newline */
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)          /* loop over each meaningless row */
            printf ("%s\n", meaningless[i]);    /* output */

        /* prompt for search, read and VALIDATE input, comparse 1st char with '\n' */
        fputs ("\nenter search term: ", stdout);
        if (!fgets (search, MAXC, stdin) || *search == '\n')
            break;

        search[strcspn (search, "\n")] = 0;     /* trim trailing '\n' from search */

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)          /* loop over each meaningless row */
            matches += wordsearch (meaningless[i], search); /* check for matches */

        printf ("\n\"%s\" found %d times.\n", search, matches); /* output results */
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/wordsearch

AMENFELANGUAGEFERVZ0PIBMOU
ZBPOINTERSSKLM12PMNOCOT
YCPROGRAMMERWQKNULTHMD
UKUNIXFIMWXIZEQZINPUTEX
P0DSTRINGGDIWHIMERCERLS

enter search term: foo

"foo" found 0 times.

AMENFELANGUAGEFERVZ0PIBMOU
ZBPOINTERSSKLM12PMNOCOT
YCPROGRAMMERWQKNULTHMD
UKUNIXFIMWXIZEQZINPUTEX
P0DSTRINGGDIWHIMERCERLS

enter search term: STRING

"STRING" found 1 times.

AMENFELANGUAGEFERVZ0PIBMOU
ZBPOINTERSSKLM12PMNOCOT
YCPROGRAMMERWQKNULTHMD
UKUNIXFIMWXIZEQZINPUTEX
P0DSTRINGGDIWHIMERCERLS

enter search term: POINTER

"POINTER" found 1 times.

AMENFELANGUAGEFERVZ0PIBMOU
ZBPOINTERSSKLM12PMNOCOT
YCPROGRAMMERWQKNULTHMD
UKUNIXFIMWXIZEQZINPUTEX
P0DSTRINGGDIWHIMERCERLS

enter search term: WHIMERCERLS

"WHIMERCERLS" found 1 times.

AMENFELANGUAGEFERVZ0PIBMOU
ZBPOINTERSSKLM12PMNOCOT
YCPROGRAMMERWQKNULTHMD
UKUNIXFIMWXIZEQZINPUTEX
P0DSTRINGGDIWHIMERCERLS

enter search term: BYE

"BYE" found 0 times.

AMENFELANGUAGEFERVZ0PIBMOU
ZBPOINTERSSKLM12PMNOCOT
YCPROGRAMMERWQKNULTHMD
UKUNIXFIMWXIZEQZINPUTEX
P0DSTRINGGDIWHIMERCERLS

enter search term:
```

Digest the code one line-at-a-time. Read the man page for each unfamiliar function and learn how it is used, the type of parameters it takes and the type and value it returns (both on success and on failure). Let me know if you have further questions.

---

Per the Comment, `strstr()` effectively combines both `strchr()` and `strncmp()` for you. It does everything done manually in `wordsearch()` in a single function call, but hides most of the details from you. You can loop finding each occurrence of `search` in `meaningless` reducing your `wordsearch()` to:

```
/* seach haystack for needle, return no. of times needle occurs */
int wordsearch (const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    const char *p = haystack;               /* string to search within */
    int found = 0;                          /* no. of matches found */

    /* loop while pointer more than nlen chars from end and 1st char in needle found */
    while ((p = strstr (p, needle))) {      /* loop finding each needle in haystack */
        found += 1;                         /* increment found by 1 */
        p += 1;                             /* increment point to next char */
    }

    return found;   /* return no. of needles in haystack */
}
```

There are many ways to write the function.

Comment: Wow, that has helped me out a lot. And I really appreciate the help. However, I am quite new to C, therefore, I found the haystack and needle part with hlen and size_t confusing is it possible to simplify it further

Comment: is it also possible to use a scanf for user input instead of fgets and fputs

Comment: Sorry, if you look at the man page for `strstr()` even a slightly easier way to do what what was done with `strchr()` and `strncmp()` that is where the needle and haystack analogy comes from, e.g. `char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);`. You may want to try and replace the `while` and `if` in `wordsearch()` with simply `while ((p = strstr (p, needle))) { found += 1; p += 1; }` which combines the `strchr` and `strncmp` into a single function. Yes, you can replace `fgets()` and `search[strcsppn()]` with `scanf`, but then how will you know when the user is done with input?

Comment: You would want to continue to use `fputs()` as there is no need for `printf` to output the prompt -- there is no conversion involved. In fact, most compilers will make that optimization for you, but it is good to show you are using the correct tool for the job.

Comment: Actually i fixed that error but after it asks the user to enter a word it doesn't allow the user to type anything

Comment: Oh, oh.... You didn't really say `gets()` did you?? see [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) and never, never use it `:)` But good job in fixing your issue. Don't rush learning C. It's more of a journey than a race. Nobody ever learns it all - they tweak the standard every now and then. Pay attention to the details. There is a lot there, so you learn C the same way you eat a whale -- one byte at a time... Edit and add where you are stuck and I'll help further.

Comment: I used what you said but I changed some of it and now it partially works .Thanks for the help soo much David. You have really helped me out. Is it possible to delete this message since I'm sending my coursework and this could screw it up?